# Use MVC to Route to Custom JavaScript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to have MVC handle the routing of certain JavaScript files in my project. Specifically, I have the following directory structure:

```
+-- Custom
|   +-- ViewModels
|      +-- Dashboard
|         +-- module1.js
+-- ViewModels
|   +-- Dashboard
|      +-- module1.js
|      +-- somefileX.js
|   +-- Profile
|      +-- somefileY.js
```

I would like to have a request for `/ViewModels/Dashboard/module1.js` to be routed to `/Custom/ViewModels/Dashboard/module1.js`.

But if `/ViewModels/Dashboard/somefileX.js` is requested, then that route doesn't go to the Custom folder.

How do I enable this? It seems like I'll need this `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;`.

Comment: What did you try so far? You can map via web.config using urlMappings element.

Comment: Haven't tried anything just yet. But was thinking about doing something similar to [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/asp-net-mvc-routing-intercepting-file-requests-like-index-html-and-what-it-teaches-about-how-routing-works). One thing is that I don't really want to have to create an actual Controller. The other is I'm unsure how to adjust this for my directory hierarchy. I don't want all JS files to be affected... just all the ones under ViewModels.

Comment: urlMappings element will let you map requests for files (that don't physically exist) to other files that do. You could also create an httpmodule. There are other ways too depending on how complex you want to make things. My first question though is why try and work against the way the system is designed to work out of the box? Most of the time there really is no good reason. Sometimes there are.

Comment: The short answer is customizations. Basically, the core/default part of the application can not know that it is being overridden. In my case, these custom files are being junctioned to that Custom folder.

Comment: Have you considered using areas to keep stuff out of the core part of the site?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions for this.

The ugly MVC Routing version looks like:

Create a route for files that has a constraint for module1.js (or the list of files you want).

```
public class MatchConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private List<string> _nonMatches;

    public MatchConstraint(params string[] nonMatches)
    {
        this._nonMatches = nonMatches.ToList();
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, 
                      Route route, 
                      string parameterName, 
                      RouteValueDictionary values, 
                      RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (!values.ContainsKey(parameterName))
            return false;

        var value = (string)values[parameterName];

        var isAllowed = this._nonMatches
          .Any(nm => nm.Equals(value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

        return isAllowed;
    }
}
```

Add the constraint to the route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Javascript",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{js}",
  defaults: new { controller = "ViewModels", 
                  action = "Dashboard", 
                  js = UrlParameter.Optional },
  constraints: new { js = new DoesNotMatchConstraint("module1.js") }
);

routes.RouteExistingFiles = true
```

Create a controller that will return the javascript file in the custom directory(s).

```
public ViewModelsController
{
  public ActionResult DashBoard(string id)
  {
    // load/pass file to FileResult
    return File();
  }
}
```

Theoretically (UNTESTED) I would assume an existing file would be served if no route was found.  If that isn't the case you can create a second catchall route for js, and return them from the standard directory.

Comment: The fact that you labeled the MVC Routing version as ugly helped lead me to abandon that path and look at HttpHanlders / Modules. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After a while I realized that while I probably could use MVC Routing to take care of finding custom JavaScript files... it probably wasn't best suited for that. I even explored creating a custom IRouteHandler.

In the end I settled on creating a HttpHandler. Here is a simplified version of what I came up with:

```
public class CustomViewModelsHandler : IHttpHandler
{
  public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
  {
    var path = context.Request.PhysicalPath.Replace("ViewModels\\", "Custom\\ViewModels\\");
    path = (File.Exists(path) ? path : context.Request.PhysicalPath);
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/x-javascript";
    context.Response.WriteFile(path);
  }
}
```

And in the web.config:

```
<add name="CustomViewModelsHandler" path="ViewModels/*.js" verb="*" type="My.Name.Space.CustomViewModelsHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```